# Predicting with differenced/stationary time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

I'm working through the book Forecasting Principles and Practice, 3rd Edition by Rob J Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos (which is excellent!). Part of chapter nine discusses Stationarity and differencing. This can be found at: [Forecasting Principles and Practice, 3rd Edition](https://otexts.com/fpp3/stationarity.html)

However, the forecasts I made using differenced data are not even close to the actual values. For example, determine how many differences are needed to make this data stationary:

```
library(fpp3)
library(tidyverse)

# Determine how many differences are needed to make this data stationary:

aus_production %>% 
  features(Beer, unitroot_nsdiffs)

# Answer: 1 difference
```

If a simple prediction is made using the regular (non-differenced) data, the result is 422:

```
set.seed(314159)
aus_production %>% 
  model(
    Neural_Net = NNETAR(Beer)
  ) %>% 
  forecast(h = 1)
```

However, if the exact same prediction is made using the differenced/stationary data, the result is -7.54, which is not even close to the non-differenced predicted value:

```
set.seed(314159)
aus_production %>% 
  mutate(Beer_diff = difference(Beer)) %>% 
  model(
  Neural_Net = NNETAR(Beer_diff)  
  ) %>% 
  forecast(h = 1)
```

How are predictions made using stationary/differenced data?

Comment: The data themselves are independent of how predictions are made. You're fitting complexity-penalized non-linear models to different data, why would you expect them to be the same? Similarly, "the number of differences needed" is a theoretical, not empirical question (if you want to be *certain*) despite there being  statistical tests to try to get at this. I recommend simulating a (non-)stationary series with known parameters and predicting by hand if want to isolate the source of your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

My error is that I was confused about modeling on differenced data. I did not understand that differenced data is used to select the model such that the residuals are white noise, but the data are modeled on non-differenced data identified using models identified in the process.

Reference: A complete example is here: [ARIMA modeling in fable](https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima-r.html)